How to change separator line of footnote direction for arabic
Is there a way to ensure that the line of a footnote in LaTeX is compatible with Arabic text formatting?

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor,graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\setdefaultlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, Scale=1.1]{Amiri}
\newfontfamily\englishfont[Scale=1]{Amiri}

\begin{document}

 قال مالك بن...\footnote{، الجزء الأول، الصفحة: 218.}

\end{document}


Welcome to the TeX.SE community. What is the your full tex code? Please add it!

for the code I simply used \footnote functionality

You should post a minimum working example showing your settings: e.g. which document class, the packages you manage the language with, etc.

packages:
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor,graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setdefaultlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, Scale=1.1]{Amiri}
\newfontfamily\englishfont[Scale=1]{Amiri}
and a subset of tex code:
قال مالك بن...\footnote{، الجزء الأول، الصفحة: 218.}

@Random If I compile your code, I get the footnote rule aligned right. By the way, it's better to post the code within your answer, and mark it as code so that it displays nicely. If the example is complete, with \begin{document} and \end{document}, more people will help you.

@Random I added your code in the question. You can edit it if needed. As said by
Iacobus1983, the code you provided display correctly the footnote rule on the right.

Thank you guys for your help, as for the problem is now fixed, I add the following lines to my tex code and it is working fine now.
\makeatletter 
\def\footnoterule{%
 \kern-3\p@
 \hbox to \columnwidth{\hbox to
.5\columnwidth{\hss}\leaders\hrule@height.4\p@\hfill}
 \kern2.6\p@} 

